# Do native queries use naming strategy to resolve the table name in the "from" clause of the given SQL query?

Tags: jpa

I have a custom naming strategy where I add a prefix to the table names. My question is: when I create a native query (using EntityManager.createNativeQuery) should I use the prefixed name of my tables in the FROM clause of my queries or should I use the non-prefixed name (as in JPQL queries) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Native query is an SQL query, so you input what would execute in your datastore if you put it directly through JDBC. It is nothing to do with the Entities

Comment: Actually, the native query is not executed as is on the DB since native queries accept parameters (this somewhat means that the query needs to be parsed).

Comment: They accept parameters ... in the JDBC sense of parameters. So yes they are just like executing through JDBC. Depends on your JPA implementation if they do anything "special" but a native query is intended as a simple pass through to the datastore